# Forwarding to multiple destinations with Twilio functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I am new to twilio. I am trying to setup a phone number that rings multiple destinations. 
I followed [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/05/dialing-multiple-numbers-simultaneously-with-twilio.html) blog and set up a twiML script like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+1-777-777-7777</Number>
    <Sip>sip:1777xxxxxxxxxx@in.callcentric.com;region=us2</Sip>
    <Sip>sip:1777xxxxxxxxxx@in.callcentric.com;region=us2</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

However as reported by other users in the comments this does not seem to work for scenarios where the destinations are a mix of sip and numbers. In my case only the phone number rings. The sip destinations don't receive the call at all.

Is there a way to make this work? either with bins or the new twilio functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not possible to use multiple [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) nouns in a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial). [From the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip#the-sip-session):

> Currently, only one `<Sip>` noun may be specified per `<Dial>`, and the INVITE message may be sent to only one SIP endpoint. Also, you cannot add any other nouns (eg `<Number>`, `<Client>`) in the same `<Dial>` as the SIP. If you want to use another noun, set up a callback on the `<Dial>` to use alternate methods.

You could, instead, add the incoming caller to a queue with [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) and [dial each of the numbers/SIP addresses using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls). Then, when one connects, connect it to the call in the queue and disconnect the other calls. You'd need to keep a reference to the original call SID so that could connect directly to it and to each of the generated call SIDs so that you can [terminate them with the REST API too](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/modify-live-calls).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have found a workaround that is working for me. I forwarded the number to my callcentric SIP From there I can use their call treatments to ring both extensions and the PSTN number.

Comment: Ah nice, glad you got something sorted!

Comment: @philnash What would be the closest sample in c# that would accomplish mixing SIP and PSTN cell call?

Comment: I don't actually know of a C# example of that. You can [make outbound SIP calls using the REST API though](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-making-calls), so you can do so alongside an outbound call to a PSTN cell.